# Creating multiple individual info windows alongside multiple markers in Google Maps

Tags: google-maps-api-3, xml-parsing, infowindow

My project searches the eBay API (using PHP and returns simpleXML) and returns the postcodes of multiple items (5 at the moment). Then uses this information to plot markers on a Google map on my website. What I am trying to do is create multiple info windows along with these markers so I can also return information from the eBay auction and put it in the info window (link to auction, picture of item etc.) but I am having no luck! I cannot seem to get the closures right in my loop and I keep getting the last postcode in the array displayed in the info window rather than the postcode actually associated with that marker (just doing this for test purposes).

What am I doing wrong? Any information will be helpful.

This is my code at the moment:

```
for (var i = 0; i < msg.length; i++) {
    info = msg[i];
    console.log(info);
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': msg[i]}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                icon: image,
                position: results[0].geometry.location
            })
            listenMarker(marker);
            markerBounds.extend(results[0].geometry.location);
            map.fitBounds(markerBounds);
        } else {
            alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        }
    });
}

function listenMarker (marker){
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infoWindow.setContent(info);
    infoWindow.open(map, this);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are need to use a function closure on the geocoder call as well (not tested), looks like you might have a problem with your listMarker function also (seems to be missing the  definition of "info", if you are depending on the global value of that, that could be your problem):

```
function geocodeAddress(msg)
{
            geocoder.geocode( { 'address': msg}, function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            icon: image,
            position: results[0].geometry.location
            })
                listenMarker(marker, msg);
                markerBounds.extend(results[0].geometry.location);
                map.fitBounds(markerBounds);
        } else {
            alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        }
    });
}

for (var i = 0; i < msg.length; i++) {
            info = msg[i];
            console.log(info);
            geocodeAddress(msg[i]);
}

function listenMarker (marker, info){
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infoWindow.setContent(info);
    infoWindow.open(map, this);
});
```

Comment: thanks! i done that and used the principles from [this blog](http://you.arenot.me/2010/06/29/google-maps-api-v3-0-multiple-markers-multiple-infowindows/) and after some fiddling it worked perfectly