# Google Maps API, Info window only displaying last element in array

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Ok, so I have been looking into this for the past few days and still can't seem to get this to work :(

I have an array of properties, which looks like this:

```
var map_markers = [
    ['London Road, Amesbury, SP4 7ER <br/> 2nd Line', 'London Road, Amesbury,', 1],
    ['Countess Court, Amesbury, SP4 7ER <br/> 2nd Line', 'Countess Court, Amesbury,', 2],
    ['Windsor Road, Salisbury, SP2 7NF <br/> 2nd Line', 'Windsor Road, Salisbury,', 3],
    ['Bishopdown Road, Salisbury, SP1 3DT <br/> 2nd Line', 'Bishopdown Road, Salisbury,', 4],
    ['Gainsborough Close, Salisbury, SP2 9HD <br/> 2nd Line', 'Gainsborough Close, Salisbury,', 5],
];
```

Now, what I want is to get an info window to pop up when the user clicks on a marker. I can get the marker code to work correctly but I am having issues binding the information to the marker, it seems to only get the last element no matter where or how I set the content. Here is my code at the moment minus the code click listener as this is what I need help with.

The content that I want to appear in my info window is the 1st element in the array for each of the properties:

```
function init_map(map_id, center_address, markers) {

    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': center_address, 'region': 'uk' }, function(results, status) {

    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) { 

         //Init Map Options
         var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 11,
            center: results[0].geometry.location,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
         }

         var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(map_id), mapOptions);

         setMarkers(map, markers);
         infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: "loading..."});

      } else {

        alert("Unable to find address: " + status);

      }

  });

}

function setMarkers(map, markers) {

        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            var locations = markers[i];
            var address = markers[i][1];

            geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address , 'region': 'uk' }, function(results, status) { 

             if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) { 

                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(results[0].geometry.location.lat(), results[0].geometry.location.lng()),
                    map: map,
                    title: address
                });

                } else {
                    alert("There was a issue getting the property information.")
                }       
        });
      }
   }
```

I know that there are lots of tutorials out there, but none of these seem to work with my code, this code be because the markers are being assigned inside a geocode function??? This is needed as my data doesnt contain Lng/Lat values.

Please note that I am a complete JS noob, so example coded would be most appreciated :)

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Word of advice; the trailing comma on the last element here: "5]," will cause problems in IE.  It's maybe just a copy-and-paste sample of your data for the purpose of the question of course...

Comment: Yes it is just a sample, but thanks for pointing this out for me :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating multiple individual info windows alongside multiple markers in Google Maps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15884175/creating-multiple-individual-info-windows-alongside-multiple-markers-in-google-m)

Answer (score 0):

The fact that it is working for the last element in the array suggests to me that you could be referencing a variable that is not declared inside the loop or you are passing the loop counter variable to another function.

In your geocode callback function you use the variable marker without the `var` declaration, this will result in a global variable called `marker` being created, which all the subsequent executions of the callback will overwrite. Once the geocoding has been done `marker` will reference the last marker added.

I would also probably bind the click of the marker at the same time as it is created, something like:

```
function setMarkers(map, markers) {
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        var locations = markers[i];
        var address = markers[i][1];
        // store the infowindow content for this marker
        var infocontent=locations[0];
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address , 'region': 'uk' }, function(results, status) { 
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) { 
                // use var to stop our marker getting overwritten
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(results[0].geometry.location.lat(), results[0].geometry.location.lng()),
                    map: map,
                    title: address
                });
                // bind to the click event of the marker
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                    var infwin=new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: infocontent});
                    infwin.open(marker);
                });

            } else {
                alert("There was a issue getting the property information.")
            }       
        });
    }
}
```